# Python readline()

Tags: python

I want to send some parameters from arduino to raspberry pi via serial. I must to send every 0.5 seconds this three parameters at the same time which are numbers to raspberry pi.

Arduino code:

```
    #include "DHT.h"
    #define echo 7
    #define triger 8
    #define photoresistorPin A0
    int lux; //Variable for photoresistor reading
    DHT dht;


    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      dht.setup(2);
      pinMode(7,INPUT);
      pinMode(8,OUTPUT);

    }

    void loop() {
      lux = analogRead(photoresistorPin);
      float temperature = dht.getTemperature();
      long duration, distance;
      digitalWrite(triger, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(2);
      digitalWrite(triger, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(10);
      digitalWrite(triger, LOW);
      duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
      distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;
      Serial.println(temperature);
      Serial.println(distance);
      Serial.println(lux);
      delay(500);

    }
```

And i recived with python code:

```
import serial
ser= serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)

while True:
   line = ser.readline()
   print(line.decode("utf-8"))
```

Results are:

```
24 #temp
112 #distance
524 #lux
```

Question is:

How to read and put separately each of them in some variable?
Example: I want to read from serial these three parameters and put them separately in some variable for example variable temp =24 for temperature from arduino, after 0.5sec 25, then 24,25,23,25.. and average them. 24+25+24+25+23+25/6 and print results. 
So the same for distance and lux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you read three lines at a time?

```
vars = []

def read_float(ser):
    return float(ser.readline().decode("utf-8"))

while True:
   vars.append([ read_float(ser), read_float(ser), read_float(ser) ])
```

Regarding "every 5 minutes", look into the `sleep` function, and probably `threading`

Comment: I'd take the opportunity to also convert to `int` or `float` while reading so the lists will already contain numbers when OP calculates the averages.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't sure if they were always numbers

Comment: @cricket_007. How would you average them if they weren't?

Comment: They are always numbers

Comment: A list of tuples would be preferable, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Why not this?

```
import serial
from collections import defaultdict
ser= serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
var = ['temp', 'distance', 'lux']
val_dict = defaultdict(list)

while True:
   line = ser.readline()
   val = zip(var,line.decode("utf-8")))
   for k, v in val:
       val_dict[k].append(float(v))


defaultdict(list, {'distance': [112.0], 'lux': [524.0], 'temp': [24.0]})
```

Comment: Because this simply prints the data in another format and doesn't help OP  achieve what they ask for.

Comment: @DeepSpace The example provided is just that. The OP could modify the code to save the `dict` into a variable instead of printing it, and handle them accordingly. It's also scalable.

Comment: modified it since it seems OP wants to save every value